# Custom response in place of "error": "invalid_grant"

Tags: json, oauth, refresh-token

I'm using oAuth 2.0 in ASP.NET web API.

In refresh token provider class I have code like this.

```
public Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{

    string tokenId = context.Token;

    var protectedTicket = WebApiBusiness.GetProtectedTicket(tokenId);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(protectedTicket))
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(protectedTicket);
        var result = WebApiBusiness.RemoveRefreshToken(tokenId);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.ContentLength = 200;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var ML_DefaultRes = new ML_DefaultRes()
        {
            ResponseCode = ResponseCodes.TokenInvalidRC,
            APIVersion = apiversion,
            ErrorDescription = ResponseCodes.GetRCDescription(ResponseCodes.TokenInvalidRC)
        };
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ML_DefaultRes);
        context.Response.Write(str);
        return;
    }
}
```

When refresh token is not valid I want custom response in JSON format.
But instead of setting content length to 200 it is taking content length upto 25 only, which makes invalid JSON response.

Is their any way to make this happen?